# 3 divs -- two are changed by one hover css

Tags: css, hover

I have 3 divs

*in this order*
**1 -  2  - 3**

I want to change  the *background* of **1**  &  **3**  when I hover over **2**  (using css)

so far  only div **3** will change

Comment: CSS has no previous-element selector, this can be approximated with CSS, but not perfectly. The best solution, for this problem, is to use JavaScript.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's difficult to make any sort of guesses as to what your problem is.

Comment: A possible duplicate of [Change color of sibling elements on hover using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574668/change-color-of-sibling-elements-on-hover-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

Use the classes to style them on hover in your CSS. Example:

```
<div class="one"> First </div>
<div class="two"> Second </div>
<div class="three"> Third </div>



.one:hover, .three:hover {
 background: pink; 
 }
```